# send arraylist to fragment to dynamically fill data

Tags: java, android

i'm making a viewpager with cardview to dynamically show the services that i have active. these services arrive by means of a json from my api, until here everything ok. i take out the data of the json and i save them in an arraylist which i pass to the CardFragmentPagerAdapter and from there i generate the corresponding cardview.

The point is that I need to pass the same array to the Fragment to there be able to put the name, description, photo etc. of each cardview and also assign the id for later use.

I have this code of an example that I found. I hope you can help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxdA9.png)

this is the main activity

```
    movidata.nombre = "Servicio por dias"
    movidata.desc = "venta de servicio por dias de 4 u 8 horas"
    movidata.foto = "ok"
    movidata.id = "2"
    data.add(movidata)



    guardar_servicios()

    val viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager

    val pagerAdapter = CardFragmentPagerAdapter(this,supportFragmentManager, dpToPixels(2, this), data)
    val fragmentCardShadowTransformer = ShadowTransformer(viewPager, pagerAdapter)
    fragmentCardShadowTransformer.enableScaling(true)

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, fragmentCardShadowTransformer)
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
```

this is the adapter

```
public class CardFragmentPagerAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements CardAdapter{


private List<CardFragment> fragments;
private float baseElevation;
public ArrayList<servicio> objectList;
Context mContext ;

public CardFragmentPagerAdapter(Context mContext ,FragmentManager fm, float baseElevation, ArrayList<servicio> objects ) {


    super(fm);
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    this.baseElevation = baseElevation;
    this.objectList = objects;
    this.mContext = mContext;

    for(int i = 0; i< objectList.size(); i++){
        addCardFragment(new CardFragment());
        objectList.get(i).getNombre();

    }
}


@Override
public float getBaseElevation() {
    return baseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position).getCardView();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return fragments.size();
    return objectList.size();
}



@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return CardFragment.getInstance(position);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragments.set(position, (CardFragment) fragment);
    return fragment;
}

public void addCardFragment(CardFragment fragment) {
    fragments.add(fragment );
}
```

}

this is the fragment

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment {
private CardView cardView;

JSONArray obj;

public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
    CardFragment f = new CardFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}


@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_servicios, container, false);


    cargarpreferencias();


    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    cardView.setMaxCardElevation(cardView.getCardElevation() * CardAdapter.MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);



    title.setText(String.format("Card %d", getArguments().getInt("position")));


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button in Card " + getArguments().getInt("position")
                    + "Clicked!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public CardView getCardView() {
    return cardView;
}
```

and this is the interface of the fragment

```
public interface CardAdapter {

public final int MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR = 8;

float getBaseElevation();

CardView getCardViewAt(int position);

int getCount();

Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position);
```

}

what I want is to be able to change according to the main arraylist the field that says Cardtitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much seeing, I found that it is easier to do what I want with a PagerAdapter, here I leave the code

this is the Adapter

```
public class AdapterServicios extends PagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {


private List<Model_Servicios> mData;
private List<CardView> mViews;
private float baseElevation;

public AdapterServicios(float baseElevation) {

    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    this.baseElevation = baseElevation;

}

public void addCardItem(Model_Servicios item) {
    mViews.add(null);
    mData.add(item);
```

}

```
public float getBaseElevation() {
    return baseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    return mViews.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position)  {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_servicios, container, false);

    container.addView(view);
    bind(mData.get(position), view, container.getContext());
    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);


    /*if (baseElevation == 0) {
        baseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
    }*/

    final int page = position;

    Button button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_service);

    cardView.setMaxCardElevation(baseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
    mViews.set(position, cardView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (page ==0 ){

                Intent intent = new Intent(container.getContext(), Login_Activity.class);
                container.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(),"Aseo por dias", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (page == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(),"Aseo 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (page == 2){
                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(),"Aseo 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else
                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(),"Aseo 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
    return view;

}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
    mViews.set(position, null);
}


private void bind(Model_Servicios item, View view, Context context) {


    ImageView imageView;
    TextView titulo, descrip;

    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_service);
    titulo =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_service);
    descrip =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_service);


    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_service);
    TextView contentTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_service);

    titleTextView.setText(item.getNombre());
    contentTextView.setText(item.getDescripcion());


    String url = item.getFoto();


    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView);

}
```

}

ActivityMain

```
                            mCardShadowTransformer = ShadowTransformer(viewPager, mCardAdapter)




                        viewPager.setAdapter(mCardAdapter)
                        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, mCardShadowTransformer)
                        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
```